# Issue while create and setup scala project

Tags: scala.js

I just start to learn `scala` and I'm facing some issues to create a new project.

I'm [following](https://medium.com/@michaelmangial1/getting-started-with-scala-js-scalavue-and-scalareact-for-the-javascript-developer-ac578ddcb5a8) this link.

I'm creating a new project of scala.js to work in front-end with Angular.

[image: issue]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please remove double quote this way and put like this way -> `""`

As I can see you had just copy and past from link. Just replace it and it may fixed your issue.

Comment: Thanks, it works for me. Now I got another version error. But I'll look into that. :)